# Random Decimals Behind A Number

Tags: javascript

Every time I do something like + 1.6 or something that's a decimal, I get a lot of random numbers spammed behind the result. how to avoid?

Comment: could you please provide more information? such as what's the calculation you are trying to perform, what is your expected result and what's the actual result you're getting

Comment: round the result to desired precision?

Answer (score -2):

var test = 1.2345;
console.log(test.toFixed(2))

// It will trim the result to the specified decimal places.
// |----> output will be 1.23 in thid case... It will keep upto 2 decimal places